# Can not wrap the text using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.I am binding some array of data on my HTML page using `ng-repeat` in Angular.js. I am explaining the code below.

```
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="plan in viewUnitData | orderBy:'user_name' " flex="20" layout-wrap>
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{plan.colg_name}}</td>
<td>{{plan.dept_name}}</td>
<td>{{plan.session}}</td>
<td>{{plan.user_name}}</td>
<td>{{plan.short_name}}</td>
<td >{{plan.semester}}</td>
<td >{{plan.subject_name}}</td>
<td >{{plan.section_name}}</td>
<td >{{plan.unit_name}}</td>
</tbody>
```

Here my problem is if college name length is more this totally table is scrolling side to side.So i thought to wrap the text so that the scroll problem will not arise but it can not wrap the text.Here I need if length will be more than `20` it will break and rest line will come in next line so that the scrolling will not come.Please help me.

Comment: using material deisgn?

Comment: No,I am using `UI-Router`.

Comment: why you have used  flex="20" ?

Comment: I did not know.I need to stop the scrolling.Somewhere i saw this was used.Can you please give me the solution.

Comment: Uses CSS: `word-wrap: break-word;` for the elements you want to wrap text

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon : Ok,but how will fix the particular length to wrap.

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon : I used this but its not working.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of td in css ? checkout this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/midhunadarvin/4b3RZ/740/

Comment: @MidhunDarvin : I tested,It is overlapping into another cell text not wrapping.